# Change js.erb based off of current route?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using AJAX in a Rails app so that when someone creates a friendship the button updates. The problem is that there are two places where they can create friendships and each has a slightly different design, one has smaller buttons.

I've created two helpers to display the buttons.

**User Helpers**

```
module UsersHelper

def action_buttons(user)
    case current_user.friendship_status(user) when "friends"
        link_to(friendship_path(current_user.friendship_relation(user)), method: :delete, :remote => true, data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Canceling"}, class: "js-cancel-friendship-btn btn btn-danger btn-sm") do content_tag(:i, "", class: "fa fa-times fa-fw", style: "color: #ffffff;") + " Cancel Friendship" end
    when "pending"
        link_to(friendship_path(current_user.friendship_relation(user)), method: :delete, :remote => true, data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Canceling"}, class: "js-cancel-request-btn btn btn-danger btn-sm") do content_tag(:i, "", class: "fa fa-times fa-fw", style: "color: #ffffff;") + " Cancel Request" end
    when "requested"
        link_to(accept_friendship_path(current_user.friendship_relation(user)), method: :put, :remote => true, data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Accepting"}, class: "js-accept-friendship-btn btn btn-primary btn-sm")  do content_tag(:i, "", class: "fa fa-plus fa-fw", style: "color: #ffffff;") + " Accept Friendship" end +
        link_to(friendship_path(current_user.friendship_relation(user)), method: :delete, :remote => true, data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Declining"}, class: "js-decline-friendship-btn btn btn-danger btn-sm m-l-sm") do content_tag(:i, "", class: "fa fa-times fa-fw", style: "color: #ffffff;") + " Decline" end
    when "not_friends"
        link_to(friendships_path(user_id: user.id), method: :post, :remote => true, data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Requesting"}, class: "js-not-friend-btn btn btn-primary btn-sm") do content_tag(:i, "", class: "fa fa-plus fa-fw", style: "color: #ffffff;") + " Send Friend Request" end
    end
end

def action_buttons_profile(user)
    case current_user.friendship_status(user) when "friends"
        link_to "Cancel Friendship", friendship_path(current_user.friendship_relation(user)), method: :delete, :remote => true,  class: "js-cancel-friendship-btn mr10"
    when "pending"
        link_to "Cancel Request", friendship_path(current_user.friendship_relation(user)), method: :delete, :remote => true, class: "js-cancel-request-btn mr10"
    when "requested"
        link_to("Accept Friendship", accept_friendship_path(current_user.friendship_relation(user)), method: :put, :remote => true, class: "js-accept-friendship-btn btn btn-primary btn-xs") +
        link_to("Decline", friendship_path(current_user.friendship_relation(user)), method: :delete, :remote => true, class: "js-decline-btn btn btn-gold btn-xs")
    when "not_friends"
        link_to "Request Friendship", friendships_path(user_id: user.id), method: :post, :remote => true, class: "js-not-friend-btn btn btn-primary btn-sm mr10"
    end
end

end
```

My issue is that the js.erb files (create/accept/destroy) always injects one helper. It's not smart enough to know what page it's outputting to. Is there a way to switch line 2 of the js.erb file that includes the helper to run? Or should this switch be someplace else? I don't want to duplicate create and destroy methods in the controller just to include this one little variance.

**Create.js.erb**

```
$('.js-not-friend-btn').bind('ajax:success', function() {
  $('.action-button-for-<%= @user.id %>').html('<%= j action_buttons(@user) %>');
  $('.js-pending-count').html('<%= @pending_count %>');
  $('.js-not-friend-btn').unbind();
});

toastr.options = {
 closeButton: true,
 progressBar: true,
 showMethod: 'slideDown',
 preventDuplicates: true,
 timeOut: 3000
};
toastr.success('','Friendship Requested!');
```

**Friendships Controller**

```
def create
    @friendship = current_user.request_friendship(@user)
    respond_to do |format|

        get_counts()
        if @user.email_notify_friend_received
            ApplicationMailer.delay.friendship_requested(current_user,@user)
        end

        format.html {redirect_to users_path, notice: "Friendship Requested"}
        format.js
    end
end

def destroy
    @user = @friendship.user == current_user ? @friendship.friend : @friendship.user

    Friendship.transaction do
        @friendship.destroy
        a = Subscription.where(user_id: @friendship.friend, subscribe_to_id: @friendship.user )
        a.first.destroy unless a.first.nil?
        b = Subscription.where(user_id: @friendship.user, subscribe_to_id: @friendship.friend )
        b.first.destroy unless b.first.nil?
    end

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to users_path, notice: "Friendship Deleted"}
        format.js
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you not just use `<% if @some_condition_from_the_controller %>` insert one javascript statement `<% else %>` insert another javascript statement `<% end %>` in your create.js.erb?

Comment: That makes sense but not sure how to pass something extra when both helpers use the same controller.

Comment: So you have not said how you would know where to display one set of action buttons vs the other. Does the controller know this - i.e. it renders one page with such buttons and another page with a different set of buttons? If so, can you use that conditional logic? Or are the two sets of buttons *on the same page*?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out how to solve this. In the helpers I changed the class of the button that I am using to trigger the JS. I then, in the create.js.erb file have two blocks, one for each button. Now the button that is on the page will get updated and the other will get ignored.

**New Create.js.erb**

```
$('.js-not-friend-btn').bind('ajax:success', function() {
 $('.action-button-for-<%= @user.id %>').html('<%= j action_buttons(@user) %>');
 $('.js-pending-count').html('<%= @pending_count %>');
 $('.js-not-friend-btn').unbind();
});

$('.js-profile-not-friend-btn').bind('ajax:success', function() {
 $('.action-button-for-<%= @user.id %>').html('<%= j action_buttons_profile(@user) %>');
 $('.js-pending-count').html('<%= @pending_count %>');
 $('.js-not-friend-btn').unbind();
});

toastr.options = {
closeButton: true,
progressBar: true,
showMethod: 'slideDown',
preventDuplicates: true,
timeOut: 3000
};
toastr.success('','Friendship Requested!');
```